# How to show/hide an element depending on its previous element in React (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to do this common "Read more.." and "Read less" for paragraphs larger than X lines by comparing the scrollHeight and offsetHeight, returning True/False - and right after setting up the content element - I will run the IsSeeMore method which will decide if it's displaying the "read more" button ore not (in other words - if my content element has more than X lines).

```
const ToggleMoreLess = (e: React.SyntheticEvent<EventTarget>) => {
    let targ = e.target as HTMLElement
    let parent = targ.previousSibling as HTMLTextAreaElement

    if (targ.innerText === 'See More') {
        parent.classList.remove('hideExtraText')
        targ.innerText = 'See Less'
    }
    else {
        parent.classList.add('hideExtraText')
        targ.innerText = 'See More'
    }
}


const IsSeeMore = (scrollh:number, offseth:number) => {
    if (scrollh === offseth)
        return false
    else 
        return true 
}

return (<ul className='item'>
    {filteredItems.map((item) => (<li key={item.id} className='item'>
        <div className='hide-btn'> Hide </div>
        <h5 className='title'>{item.title}</h5>
        <p className='content hideExtraText' id={`c-${item.id}`}>{item.content}</p>
        { 
            ( IsSeeMore(document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(`c-${item.id}`)!.scrollHeight, document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(`c-${item.id}`)!.offsetHeight) ) ? <p className='seemore' onClick={ToggleMoreLess}> See More </p> : null
        }
        <p className='seemore' onClick={ToggleMoreLess}> See More </p>
        <div className='labels'>
        { (item.labels !== undefined) ? item.labels.map( (label, i) => <span key={i}> {label} </span> ) : null }
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div className='meta-data'>By {item.userEmail} | { new Date(item.creationTime).toLocaleString()}</div>
        </footer>
    </li>))}
</ul>);
```

}

this is the error i am getting:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'scrollHeight'
> of null ▶ 22 stack frames were collapsed. This screen is visible only
> in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
> Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
> Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message

So I am guessing this isn't possible?
what's the best efficient way running this function and getting a true/false result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This misses something important about React: the elements aren't necessarily in the DOM at render time, and the elements in your JSX aren't the literal items rendered into the DOM, so you can't query them during component rendering via `querySelectorAll` and friends - they don't exist in the DOM at that point. Measuring things like scrollHeight are meaningless in that context. Instead, you want to use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

I've done this example as a functional component because it's simpler, but the same principles apply to class components.

```
function Overflowable({children}) {
  const [ref, setRef] = useState(null);
  return <p ref={ref => setRef(ref)}>{children}</p>
}
```

The `ref` attribute on the element causes React to invoke a function passing the DOM node when the node changes. In this case, we're going to capture it with a `useState` updater, because we want the element to rerender after the DOM node reference changes. If you didn't want a rerender, you would use `useRef`.

Then, once we have that reference, we can do things with the reference to see what's going on in the DOM. In this case we're just going to interrogate the node to compare its scrollHeight and offsetHeight, and set a flag that we'll use to alter how the component is displayed:

```
function Overflowable({children}) {
  const [ref, setRef] = useState(null);
  const isOverflow = ref && ref.scrollHeight != ref.offsetHeight;
    return <>
      <p ref={ref => setRef(ref)}>{children}</p>
      {isOverflow && <a href="#" onClick={toggle}>See More</a>}
    </>
}
```

Finally, we want some way to force the component to re-render when the window resizes. To do that, we wire up the window's `resize` event to force a state invalidation, which causes our component to re-render:

```
  const [, setWindowWidth] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const f = () => setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
    window.addEventListener("resize", f);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", f);
  }, [setWindowWidth]);
```

[You can see it all together in action here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-galileo-tnxgq?file=/src/App.js)